# htaccess Rewrite Rule Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have youtube script to show youtube videos and My .htaccess has contain :

```
RewriteRule ^watch-([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{11})$ watch.php?id=$1 [L]
```

my video link is : http://name.com/watch-h5u665uhiu

my watch.php file has contain

```
 $link = "watch-#ID#";
```

i want to change "watch-" to "watch?v=" to be same youtube

when i put "watch?v=" in .htaccess file and change "watch-" in watch.php file the link shown 404 Error
because it contains "?" , if i delete "?" its work normally .
how i can make the link contains "?" without errors ?

Comment: Little difficult to understand. What is `#ID#` in the link? Is it a placeholder? What is the need of replacing `"watch-" to "watch?v="`?

Comment: @anubhava sorry , yes , #id# the youtube video id .and yes i want to replace "watch-" to "watch?v="

Comment: Sorry still not clear. Can you place code from your `watch.php` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{11})$ watch.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dash, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^watch-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{11})$ watch.php?v=$1 [L]
```